# How to add url in products in user end

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

Hi there Its been a week I'm stuck on one thing I want users when their order is completed and shown in their account section they can simply click on that order after clicking they can move to there specific order they purchased, I don't know how to explain lemme add Screen shot[image: Here you can know better what I want]

Can someone elaborate on how I can link those products on the user end when someone wants to see their orders by just clicking as you can see in the attached image

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_thankyou', 'goto_order_view', 10, 1);

function goto_order_view($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    ?>

        <a href="<?php echo esc_url($order->get_view_order_url()); ?>">
    <?php echo esc_html(_x('View Order #', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce') . $order->get_order_number()); ?>
                                    </a>
    <?php
}
```

Add this code to your active theme functions.php file.